# 404 on Resource/Class Link

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I'm trying to figure out this issue where I can't find the URL to my class. I've done some debugging, and the class is indeed loaded in, but not loaded as a resource (should it be?). Firing up the Grizzly server and Jersey will load everything, however, trying to connect to my class (path is /createserver) at localhost:8080/createserver will always fail with a 404, and using the servlet name (kyrapanel) in the URL like localhost:8080/kyrapanel/createserver would lead to the Google Chrome 404 page, rather than the one generated by Grizzly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not running it using tomcat or anything of the sort, I'm using the Grizzly servlet and embedding it into the JAR.

Comment: have you enabled logs?

Comment: @saurabh I'm pretty sure logging is enabled by default, as whenever Grizzly starts it logs this:

`Apr 27, 2017 8:20:27 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8080]
Apr 27, 2017 8:20:27 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.`

Comment: it appears to have info level logs good. you can also enable debug/trace logs (e.g. in log4j) based on logging implementation used

Comment: @saurabh According to some answers on StackOverflow, Grizzly utilizes the base Logger supplied in Java, and not external loggers such as Log4J.